# Expected an indented block on an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

```
# Check for log request
if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    if sys.argv[3].lower() == 'log':
        logFiles = True
```

I haven't done Python for a while but I don't see anything wrong with the above code and it's saying that after the 'logFiles' before the = True is the problem.

Ideas?

Comment: `.lower()` missing parentheses

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: try it by replacing tabs with space

Comment: Oh that works, that's odd..

Comment: if you are using vim ( which you should `:)` ), you may add `set expandtab` in `.vimrc` file and it will always insert space instead of tabs.

Comment: Maybe an additional problem to watch out for: if `len(sys.argv)` is actually 3, then `sys.argv[3]` indexes the 4th element and you should get an IndexError. I guess you meant `sys.argv[2]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2 treats a tab the same way Notepad does - as enough spaces to reach the next 8-space indentation level. This means if you mix tabs and spaces, you might see code that looks perfectly well indented, but Python sees a garbled mess. (In Python 3, Python will give you a helpful `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` if it sees that you're mixing tabs and spaces.) Your code has a tab on the second line and 4 spaces and a tab on the second. This looks like 1 indent, then 2, but Python doesn't see it that way.

Don't mix tabs and spaces. If you can, use the `-tt` interpreter option to detect this, and use an editor with an option to display whitespace characters.